# How do I translate this ImageMagick command into its PHP Imagick equivalent?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#cube3d) "tutorial" in the ImageMagick documentation, but having a lot of trouble. I want to complete the following ImageMagic command in its Imagick PHP equivelant:

```
convert -virtual-pixel transparent \
                        \( $top -matte  +distort Affine \
                            '0.5,511.5 0.5,0.5   0.5,0.5 -87.5,-50  511.5,511.5 87.5,-50' \) \
                        \( $left -matte +distort Affine \
                            '511.5,0.5 0.5,0.5   0.5,0.5 -87.5,-50  511.5,511.5 0.5,99.5' \) \
                        \( $front -matte  +distort Affine \
                            '0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5   0.5,319.5 0.5,99.5   319.5,0.5 87.5,-50.0' \) \
                        -background black -layers merge +repage \
                        -bordercolor black -border 5x2     isometric_cube_overlap.png
```

Where `$top = new Imagick('top.png');`
, `$front = new Imagick('front.png');`
, and `$left = new Imagick('left.png');`. Each of these are 512x512px png images.

I found some [rather lacking documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.affinetransformimage.php) on the Affine transformation but I have no clue what `$matrix` is supposed to be or how to even use the function. I even tried running `exec` on the actual ImageMagick command, but nothing happened. I was expecting the transformation to have been completed and saved as `isometric_cube_overlap.png`.

I could really use some help here, even if someone could just point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just run the command as such?

```
<?php 
    $cmd = " convert -virtual-pixel transparent \
                    \( $top -matte  +distort Affine \
                        '0.5,511.5 0.5,0.5   0.5,0.5 -87.5,-50  511.5,511.5 87.5,-50' \) \
                    \( $left -matte +distort Affine \
                        '511.5,0.5 0.5,0.5   0.5,0.5 -87.5,-50  511.5,511.5 0.5,99.5' \) \
                    \( $front -matte  +distort Affine \
                        '0.5,0.5 0.5,0.5   0.5,319.5 0.5,99.5   319.5,0.5 87.5,-50.0' \) \
                    -background black -layers merge +repage \
                    -bordercolor black -border 5x2     isometric_cube_overlap.png "." -distort ScaleRotateTranslate \"28,24  .4,.8  -110  50,120 \" ";
    exec("$cmd");
?>
```

Also the backslashes don't look right to me.
I bet the output of that command fails too?

Comment: *Your* command will fail, as it stands, hsmoore.com. Because it expands to a *double* `convert convert ...`. Oh, and yes: the backslashes are definitely required in front of the round brackets, otherwise the shell would try to open a subshell...